# UINavigationController -> UIViewController -> UIView -> UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiview, interface-builder, uitableview

Inside Interface Builder I have a UINavigationController, which contains a UIViewController, which has a UIView inside it. This **main** UIView has a bunch of labels as well as a few ImageViews and custom UIViews as well.

What I want to do though is throw a UITableView inside this **main** UIView. This UITableView will take up about half the screen in the UIView. I'm trying to add a UITableViewController below the UIView but everytime I do it, the UITableViewController object replaces my UIViewController object in IB??

What am I doing wrong?

I want:

  UINavigationController
    UIViewController
      UIView
        UITableViewController (since the UTableView will be inside the preceding UIView)

Where am I going wrong in this setup? When I try to add the UITableViewController in IB I get:

  UINavigationController
    UITableViewController (..err? Why's it replacing my ViewController?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After putting UITableView into UIView instead of UITableViewController, and then set table view's delegate and data source to UIViewController.
Naturally, UIViewController should implements two protocol (table view deleate and data source).

Comment: yes. Did a bunch of reading on how UITableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController and some blogs even make arguments for **never** using UITableViewController. I'm fine. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need table view controller at all. You have to add UITableView and implement all necessary data source and delegate methods in your view controller.